# React. How to add class in element on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. Currently I'm creating one app in learning purposes. 
I'm stuck trying to change color of button on click. When I click on a button, the color of all the buttons are changed. But I need to have just one button active, while others are not active. When I click on different button, the previous active button loses its class and become inactive.
Could you help me out?

```
state = {
  clicked: false
};

timeChangeHandler = () => {
  this.setState({ clicked: true });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        className={
          this.state.clicked
            ? "list-group-item list-group-item-action active"
            : "list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        }
        onClick={this.timeChangeHandler}
      >
        8:00
      </button>

      <button
        type="button"
        className={
          this.state.clicked
            ? "list-group-item list-group-item-action active"
            : "list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        }
        onClick={this.timeChangeHandler}
      >
        9:00
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi. You should add your code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to SO. I agree with @Andy. If you provide a minimal example we can help you better. But, you are probably can't keep a separate "clicked" state. You should have a "clicked" state and keep your button's id or anything else unique to get the state right and change your class conditionally.

Comment: React is all about state. What you describe sounds like you're storing a single boolean value; what you need instead is an integer value, namely the index of the currently active button. Clicking a button updates the state to point to itself.

Comment: Sorry, I added my code.

Comment: Here's an example app: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hertz-xesgx

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I learnt a lot today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can do it. I map the buttons and use index as the clicked value. But, if you are using your buttons statically as in your code you can use @Kyle's solution.

```js
const buttons = [
  {
    name: "foo"
  },
  {
    name: "bar"
  },
  {
    name: "baz"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clicked: null
  };

  handleClick = id => this.setState({ clicked: id });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {buttons.map((button, index) => (
          <button
            className={this.state.clicked === index && "clicked"}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}
          >
            {button.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would look something like this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            activeButton: 0
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { activeButton } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    className={ activeButton === 0 && "active" }
                    onClick={() => this.setState({activeButton: 0})}
                />

                <button
                    className={ activeButton === 1 && "active" }
                    onClick={() => this.setState({activeButton: 1})}
                />

                <button
                    className={ activeButton === 2 && "active" }
                    onClick={() => this.setState({activeButton: 2})}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot!